# POST method not being submitted by form django

Tags: python, html, django

I have two radio buttons and i want one of them to be selected and send to my Django views.py template.I can't use django.forms for specific reasons.Basically i want to add the value of the radio button pressed into a column named 'q1'in the hardware model.But as I press submit the print(req.POST.get('question_type'))" shows None in the console.

HTML:-

```
    <form action="{% url 'hardwareq1' %}" method="POST">
{% csrf_token %}
      <label class="btn  btn-success"> <input type="radio" id="control_1" name="question_type" value="Indoor" />Indoor
      </label> 
      <label class="btn  btn-success" > <input type="radio" id="control_1" name="question_type" value="Outdoor" />Outdoor
      </label>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-secondary btn-block" />
    </form>
```

urls.py

```
path('hardwareq1',views.hardware1,name='hardwareq1'),
```

views.py:-

```
def hardware1(req):
    h=HardwareModel.objects.all().filter(productid=1)
    print(req.POST.get('question_type'))
    if req.method=='POST':
        h.q1=req.POST.get('question_type')
        h.save(force_update=True)
    context={
        'hardware':h
    }
    return render(req,'pages/shardware1.html',context)
```

model:-

```
class HardwareModel(models.Model):
    productid=models.IntegerField()
    q1=models.CharField(max_length=20,blank=True,null=True)
    q2=models.CharField(max_length=20,blank=True,null=True)
    q3=models.CharField(max_length=20,blank=True,null=True)
    q4=models.CharField(max_length=20,blank=True,null=True)
    q5=models.CharField(max_length=20,blank=True,null=True)
    q6=models.CharField(max_length=20,blank=True,null=True)
    q7=models.CharField(max_length=20,blank=True,null=True)
    q8=models.CharField(max_length=20,blank=True,null=True)
    q9=models.CharField(max_length=20,blank=True,null=True)
```

Comment: what is the error you face? could you attach your error here?

Comment: Is this your actual code? I suspect it isn't, and that you're not even sending that POST request. Why? Because if that was the case, Django would complain for the missing `{% csrf_token %}` tag. Moreover, it would complain in your `hardware1` view for this line -> `h.q1=req.POST.get('question_type')`, raising an `AttributeError` with a message like: "QuerySet has no 'q1' attribute".

Comment: addition to @revliscano what is the output you expect when you type req instead of request? I never saw like this one before what I know is a request argument not req arg

Comment: Check the new edit